# MySQL Workbench shows comments table as the most acccessed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out why mays.tamu.edu is so slow. It's running on wordpress, server 2012, php 6.5.6 and we've got an abundant amount of resources. I've tried different setups with caching pages etc. But what I keep coming back to is that the database is slow, not php or the server.

I went into Workbench and look at the performance reports. At the top of the I/O reports are all of these comment tables. In our wordpress setup, comments are disabled. My guess is that bots are trying to write to our blog.

I've got dynamic ip restrictions set but it seems these bots are still hitting the database. Any ideas on how to prevent them from accessing these tables?

[image: Mysql Top I/O by file by time]

Comment: offtopic, not a programming question. this is more server configuration/security.

Comment: Yes php is version 6.5.6!